# Javascript comparing strings not giving expected result

Tags: javascript

I am trying to determine the selected item in a selector and submit a form based on the selection. Below is my Javascript.

```
$("#runjob").click(function() {
            var selectedJob = document.getElementById('batchjob_selector').value.trim();
            if(selectedJob == "Open Batch") {
                alert(selectedJob);
                document.getElementById('openbatchform').submit();
            }

        });
```

I checked in the console and the line `document.getElementById('batchjob_selector').value.trim();` changes value based on selection, but for some reason it is always doing what's inside the `if` statement even when the selection has changed, the alert displays the correct selection. I am not sure what the problem is, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the posted material is sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: Possibly the "runjob" element is a "submit" button in the form involved, in which case it's going to submit the form no matter what that code does.

Comment: @Pointy that would still not explain the `alert` going off, especially displaying the correct selection which apparently differs from "Open Batch".

Comment: Yes that's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is `batchjob_selector` a `select`? because if that the case value will no contains what you are expecting, to get selected option from a `select` use following code

```
var selector = document.getElementById('batchjob_selector');
var selectedJob = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex];
```